# Squid3 suers authenitcate but no data servered

Tags: linux, debian, squid

Hi everybody!

I have Squid 3.1 running on Debian 7 from the Wheezy repos.

Users can authenticate and requests sent but pages were not displayed in browser, which sits with white screen loading forever. :(

My log file gives:
Stackoverflow won't let me post this because it thinks I'm posting links, and I lack reputation points.

And my config is:

> ```
> acl manager proto cache_object
> acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
> acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
> acl SSL_ports port 443 8443 563 22   # https, snews, ssh
> acl SSL_ports port 4443         # rsync
> acl SSL_ports port 873          # rsync
> acl Safe_ports port 80 81 82 800 8119          # http
> acl Safe_ports port 4443 873    # rsync
> acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
> acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
> acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
> acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
> acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
> acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
> acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
> acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
> acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
> acl Safe_ports port 631         # cups
> acl purge method PURGE
> acl CONNECT method CONNECT
> auth_param digest program /usr/lib/squid3/digest_pw_auth -c /etc/squid3/passwords
> auth_param digest realm proxy
> acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
> http_access allow manager localhost
> http_access allow authenticated
> http_access deny manager
> #http_access deny !Safe_ports
> #http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
> http_access allow localhost
> http_access deny all
> http_port 3128 transparent
> forwarded_for delete
> coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
> refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
> refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
> refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
> refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
> ```

I removed the denys for ports for testing:
    http_access deny !Safe_ports
    http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

Maybe this has  something to do with IP6 resolution, because my DNS will resolve IP6 addresses, but ping won't ping!

In squid log file: DIRECT/2a01:111:f400:9814::6
And failing ip5 ping.

```
# ping6 -n ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(2607:f8b0:4005:802::1000) 56 data bytes
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2000ms
```

I'd be so grateful if somebody just gave me some help?

Kind regards, 
Sophie

Answer (score 1):

The problem was DNS resolves IP6 address but my VPS server did not have an IP6 address, so squid uses IP6 and won't fall back to IP4.

IP4 can be forced by adding this my squid.conf:

tcp_outgoing_address 123.123.123.123

where 123.123.123.123  is your outgoing IP4 addresss you would like to use.

Squid now works.